# MySQL table join syntax

Tags: mysql

If I use syntax like this

```
SELECT * FROM table_1, table_2 WHERE table_1.id=table_2.id;
```

is this an INNER JOIN?  In other words, is this equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id=table_2.id;
```

Comment: yes, it is equivalent.

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause

Comment: Thanks Zak.  I worried that this was a duplicate but couldn't condense my question down to a search that answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: 
Yes, it is the same.

Most RDBMS will eventually process both syntax the same way.

Using the `INNER JOIN` is considered to be better readable, and also is the [ANSI standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

Comment: The other syntax is ANSI standard as well ;)

Comment: I know, I just didn't put it in there to avoid a religious debate about it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

For simple cases like this, it appears that the MySQL engine will optimize in the same way. I figured this out by running

```
DESCRIBE SELECT * FROM table_1, table_2 WHERE table_1.id=table_2.id;
```

and

```
DESCRIBE SELECT * FROM table_1 INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id=table_2.id;
```

which tells you a bit about how the query will run.